# How to stop JPanel content from shifting when button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, buttonclick

This concerns `JAVA` programming.
I have a confusing question that I can't seem to figure out despite searching all over the internet.
I am somewhat of a newer programmer, so this may be a relatively stupid thing to ask.

Anyways, here is my question:
I made a calculator GUI program (a simple one) that utilizes a `JPanel` with one text field, one `JButton` and one `JTextArea`.

My issue is that when I press the `JButton` and the calculated result is displayed in the `JTextArea`, if it's long enough in digits, everything above it in the `JPanel` gets shifted to the right. How do I fix this such that the content does not shift upon the button <kbd>click/refresh</kbd> of the panel?

Thanks,
-Han

Comment: Please show some code. It's hard to tell what you have going on without it.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am completely new to this forum and did not know how it operates. When I asked this question, I thought it was more of a concept rather than a "glitch" or some error within my code. Anyways, MadProgrammer has readily provided the answer to my question and my program is working as I wish now. Thank you all!

Comment: Then why don't you tick his question and let everybody else know that this question has got the answer?

Comment: My bad, I did not even notice the tick mark. I tried pressing the up button but I apparently don't have enough "reputation" for it. Excuse my noobiness, I have correctly "ticked" this question as it is now resolved. Thanks again, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you've added you textarea directly to your container without first adding it to a scrollpane.

The text area will grow as the content exceeds its current width/height.

Try adding your text area to a scroll pane and then add the scroll pane to your container...

```
textArea = new JTextArea(...)(
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
add(scrollPane);
```

Take a look at [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to use text areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details

Comment: Yes, congratulations kind sir!

Comment: @peeskillet wowho!  Now I can take a break...for 30 seconds and start working towards 200!  Thanks everybody for the up-votes :D

Comment: @user3143244 Thanks for tipping me over!

Answer (score 0):

Simple just add JTextArea in another JPanel with JScrollPane. Use appropriate Layout. Set JtextArea's lineWrap property to true.